# Unity WebGL with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core-mvc, webgl

Because I could not find solution for my issue I make this thread. I am beginner with ASP.NET Core MVC and currently am trying to create a website with Unity build game as WebGL. This is my project tree

[image]

This is my code for GamePage.cshtml

```
@page
@model GamePageModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Game";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div id="gameContainer"></div>

<script src="~/Build/TemplateData/style.css"></script>
<script src="~/Build/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>

<script src="~/Build/BUILDS.loader.js"></script>
<script src="~/Build/BUILDS.data"></script>
<script src="~/index.html"></script>

<a href="~/index.html">~/index.html</a>
```

This is the script for my GameController.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestGame02.Controllers
{
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Game()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

But when I run the game on the local server I have this error.
[image]

I apologize again for the noob question, I know that I am missing something, but I can't find what.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you referencing all the scripts in the **View** that is only `<a href...>` linking to the `index.html`?

That `index.html` is build by Unity (based on your template) and itself already an html page to be opened in the browser.

The scripts etc should only be referenced in the `index.html` itself and are most probably looking for relative things in the same folder it doesn't find due to wrong hierarchy. For instance things from `BUILDS.wasm` and `BUILDS.framework`. Also that `<script src="~/index.html"></script>` is not a script.

I think what you would rather want to do is e.g. simply redirecting to your already existing `index.html` page like

```
return Redirect("index.html");
```

Might require to add a

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

if not there already. Also note that you might have to adjust certain static file mime-types. In particular e.g. `.data` needs to be `"application/octet-stream"` and if you use compression you will need to cut off the `.br` / `.gzip` extension and also set according encoding types.

To do so and combine all that `UseStaticFiles` takes an optional parameter `StaticFileOptions` which further takes an `IContentTypeProvider`

So I think what you could do is something like

```
app.UseStaticFiles(CustomStaticFileOptions.GetOptions());
```

and

```
// Handles WebGL specific MIME and encoding types as well as file path handling for the Gzip and Brotli compressions
public static class CustomStaticFileOptions
{
    // This handles the MIME type mapping
    private class CustomContentTypeProvider : IContentTypeProvider
    {
        private const string GZIP_EXTENSION = ".gz";
        private const string BROTLI_EXTENSION = ".br";

        private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> COMPRESSION_ENCODINGS = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { GZIP_EXTENSION, "gzip" },
            { BROTLI_EXTENSION, "br" }
        };

        // This by default already knows the MIME type mappings for the most commonly used file types
        private readonly FileExtensionContentTypeProvider fileTypeProvider = new();

        public CustomContentTypeProvider()
        {
            // Can extend it with our own mappings - as mentioned in particular this one
            fileTypeProvider.Mappings[".data"] = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        // interface method used when the app tries to find a MIME mapping for a served static file 
        public bool TryGetContentType(string filePath, out string contentType)
        {
            // If this is a compressed file we need to get the actual extension
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            if (extension == GZIP_EXTENSION || extension == BROTLI_EXTENSION)
            {
                // Cutting off the .gz or .br extension and get the actual extension
                // e.g. "Build/something/image.png.gz" -> "Build/something/image.png" -> ".png"
                filePath = filePath[..^extension.Length];
                extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            }

            // then return the according MIME type
            return fileTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(filePath, out contentType);
        }
    }

    public static StaticFileOptions GetOptions()
    {
        var fileTypeProvider = new CustomContentTypeProvider();
        return new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = fileTypeProvider,
            OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            {
                // In addition to the MIME type also set the according encoding header
                if (COMPRESSION_ENCODINGS.TryGetValue(Path.GetExtension(context.File.Name), out var encoding))
                {
                    context.Context.Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = encoding;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you sugested, I have redirected the view to return index.html, but it still freezes when loading the game it is stuck on Error 404 not found Build/BUILDS.data.

Comment: repeating my last sentence: `Also note that you might have to adjust certain static file mime-types. In particular e.g. .data needs to be "application/octet-stream" and if you use compression you will need to cut off the .br / .gzip extension`

Comment: Did you add `app.UseStaticFiles();`?

Comment: Yes, I have app.UseStaticFiles(); but I am not sure that I know how to change the MIME types.

Comment: @Infinitum updated at the bottom - haven't tested this but saw similar approaches and I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Files with extension `.js` go in `script` tags.

```
<script src="path/to/my/javascipt.js"></script>
```

These should be inserted at the bottom of the html page.  MVC has a `scripts` section that will insert at the bottom of the page using

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>...</script>
}
```

Files with extension `.css` go in link tags.

```
<link href="path/to/my/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

These should be inserted in the `head` tag of the page.  Add another `RenderSection` to your `_Layout.cshtml` (inside the head tag) if the section does not already exist.

```
@RenderSection("styles", required: false)
```

Used the same as the scripts section.

```
@section styles
{
    <link href.... />
    <style>h1 { color: #000000; }</style>
}
```

Then extract the html markup from the `index.html` page.  This can be tricky if you are not comfortable with web development.  The index page will have all the different parts of the webpage: style, scripts, markup, etc. some of which can be used for any game you release.

I personally have the scripts and styles in partial views for reuse across all my games.  For this to work, create a model containing properties for the dynamic portions of the script/style, and pass that model to the partial views.

If this seems like too much or you want to get your game up quickly without tinkering too much, I suggest using the tips outlined by @derHugo.  Since unity creates the index page with everything needed, you can just show that page, just make sure all the references resolve correctly.